# Convert a file of Discord UserID's to Name#Discriminator

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a file of 10,000 user `ID`s that I would like to convert to `Name#Discriminator` format.

The only way I can think of is to use a script to ban every `userid` on a server, then print the bans list.

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: If this is a python question, why is there a javascript library on the tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward if you use [`Client.get_user_info`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_user_info) to get the `User` objects from the ids.  `str(some_user)` is `Name#Discriminator`.

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    with open("ids.txt") as infile, open("names.txt", "w+") as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            id = line.strip()  # int(line) if you're using rewrite
            user = await client.get_user_info(id)
            print(user, file=outfile)

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Answer (score 0):

Patrick's answer uses the popular library, but that is mostly for bots because it creates the websocket.

You can simply send a GET request to `https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/{user.id}`

along with an 'authorization' token as a header

i.e.

```
curl -L -X GET 'https://discordapp.com/api/v6/users/540305676191399972' -H 'authorization: xxxauthtokenxxx' -H
```

Response is in JSON